# Bluebird doesn't call then(), even with the previously working code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bluebird

I am building a node-framework for my future works, which can be easily managed. It already has a config module.

I wrote an error handler and updated the Config to use then. Since that I cannot use the `.then()` method as before. The interesting part is that **it doesn't work on the version it worked before (`git checkout`)**.

I don't know what could be the solution. Do you?

---

**What I tried until now:**

- reinstall all node_modules (globals too)
- `git checkout` to an earlier version
- fully remove and reinstall node and npm
- reinstall all node_modules (again)
- drink much coffee
- buy much beer to send them for the right answers

**I used this simple script to test the `ConfigManager`:**

```js
var Config = require('./core/server/config');

// Init the Config method
Config.load().then(function(){
    // Write out the 'url'
    console.log(Config.get('url'));
}

// Update: and I have to wait for processing or I get `undefined`
console.log(Config.get('url'));
// > undefined
```

**If I do it realtime but without the then() method, it works:**

```js
var Config = require('./core/server/config');
// > undefined
Config.load();
// > { _bitField: 0, _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined, _rejectionHandler0: undefined, _promise0: undefined, _receiver0: undefined, _settledValue: undefined, _boundTo: undefined, _traceParent: undefined, _trace: [Error] }
Config.get('url');
// > 'http://127.0.0.1'
```

---

**Note:** the `ConfigManager` has a lot in common with [TryGhost/Ghost's module](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/config/index.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. Shame on me.

Seems like when I committed/pushed the fix, I accidentally undid some changes, which I only recognised after about half a day...

**This was the problem (it could be helpful for beginners):**

```js
+   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
+       resolve(self._config);
-   return new Promise(function () {
-       return self._config;
    });
```

**Update:** Benjamin's solution is much better. The same but more compact and clear. Thanks!

```js
return Promise.resolve(self._config);
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve(self._config)` is the correct way to do this. Or alternatively if your function always returns a promise you can use `Promise.method` to wrap it and then just `return self._config`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for that. :) I'm just starting to understand these modules (and there's a lot I have to work with very soon, so I couldn't yet go too deep).